# neo4j cypher Avoid repetion of paths

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following query and I want to avoid repetions of the paths(simetric too).

```
MATCH (a:PERSON)-[:LIKES]->(b:PERSON)-[:LIKES]->(a) return a,b
```

I have try `DISTINCT` keyword but I get and syntax error.

Im looking for something like (but fails too):

```
MATCH path=(a:PERSON)-[:LIKES]->(b:PERSON)-[:LIKES]->(a) 
where DISTINCT(path)
return a,b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add a simple test to make sure that one is greater than the other that way you won't receive the same pairing more than once.

```
MATCH (a:PERSON)-[:LIKES]->(b:PERSON)-[:LIKES]->(a) 
where id(b) > id(a)
return a,b
```

Comment: I don't see it, how a <> b avoids get same pairing more than one.

Comment: not `<>` but `greater than` or `less than`.  You are matching `a-[:LIKES]->b` and reciprocally `b-[:LIKES->a`. So when you get one of these closed loop matches it works forwards and backwards.  What you are returning are the pair of nodes so for every two people they will generate two matches with one person in each position.  The principle with the comparison operator is to simply return only one of those matches. Since the ids of the nodes are always present and unique one will always be greater than the other and only return every pair once instead of twice.